# How to use XPath in VBA

Tags: xml, vba, xpath

My XML kind of looks like the snipped below.

I want to:
Select all "id" which are in the node "Issue".
Not select any ids which are elements of subnodes.

My approach `xml.SelectNodes("/config/entry/content/Issue/id")` returns an empty list.

**Here is the XML**

```
<config> 
    <id>3423</id>
    <Title>Project Overview</Title>
    <entry>
        <id>3423</id>
        <Title>Project Overview</Title>
        <content>
            <Issue>
                <id>3423</id>
                <etc...>....<etc...>
                <hasMappedReleases>
                    <id>4365<id>
                    <etc...>....<etc...>
                </hasMappedReleases>
            </Issue>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry>
          ....
          ....

</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution should work. The problem should be in another place.
I tried with this xml sample:

```
<config> 
    <id>3423</id>
    <Title>Project Overview</Title>
    <entry>
        <id>3423</id>
        <Title>Project Overview</Title>
        <content>
            <Issue>
                <id>3423</id>
                <hasMappedReleases>
                    <id>4365</id>
                </hasMappedReleases>
            </Issue>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>3424</id>
        <Title>Project Overview</Title>
        <content>
            <Issue>
                <id>3424</id>
                <hasMappedReleases>
                    <id>4367</id>
                </hasMappedReleases>
            </Issue>
        </content>
    </entry>
</config>
```

and this code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim xDoc As XmlDocument
    Dim result As XmlNodeList
    xDoc = New XmlDocument
    xDoc.Load("test.xml")
    result = xDoc.SelectNodes("/config/entry/content/Issue/id")
    Print(result.Count)
End Sub
```

and it printed me count = 2

Here is a good XPath reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256086(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Several hints/issues: a) use the current version 6.0 via `Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60`, b) **set** the declared *object* by `Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60`; c) if not used to check the boolean okay result no brackets in `xDoc.Load "test.xml"` (specify exact path!); d) a `NodeList` has a `.Length` property to count elements, d) VBA uses `Debug.Print` :-) @andymeissner